# arithmetic mean inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ and $u_{\Omega}=\mu(\Omega)^{-1}\int_{\Omega}{u}$. Why does it hold that $$\int{(u-u_{\Omega})^{2}}\leq 2 \inf_{c\in \mathbb{R}}\int{(u-c)^{2}}?$$ Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{\Omega}{(u-c)^{2}} = \int_{\Omega}{(u-u_{\Omega} + u_{\Omega} - c)^{2}}$$
$$=  \int_{\Omega}(u-u_{\Omega})^2 + 2\int_{\Omega}(u-u_{\Omega})(u_{\Omega} - c) + \int_{\Omega}(u_{\Omega} - c)^2$$
The middle term is zero since
$$\int_{\Omega}(u-u_{\Omega})(u_{\Omega} - c) = (u_{\Omega} - c)\int_{\Omega}(u-u_{\Omega})$$
$$= (u_{\Omega} - c)\bigg(\int_{\Omega}u - u_{\Omega}\,\mu(\Omega)\bigg)$$
$$=0$$
So what we have is

$$\int_{\Omega}{(u-c)^{2}}  =  \int_{\Omega}(u-u_{\Omega})^2  + \int_{\Omega}(u_{\Omega} - c)^2$$
Thus for all $c$ we have 
$$\int_{\Omega}(u-u_{\Omega})^2 \leq \int_{\Omega}{(u-c)^{2}}$$
This is stronger than what you need.

Comment: By definition $u_{\Omega} = (\int_{\Omega} u)/\mu(\Omega)$, so plug that in and you get a 0 factor.